# Canvas drawImage inline svg doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, svg

Here is a fiddle of an example that takes an svg and turns it into a canvas: http://jsfiddle.net/Na6X5/944/

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var svg = document.getElementById('mySVG');

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
console.log(img.width, img.height)
document.getElementById('canvas1').width = 300
document.getElementById('canvas1').height = 200
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 200);
}
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svg.outerHTML)
```

This works fine on Chrome(51.0). But produces an empty canvas on Firefox(47.0.1) with no errors.

This example works on Firefox http://codepen.io/keithwyland/pen/umova but changing the src of the image to an inline svg produces the problem listed above http://codepen.io/Ewhite613/pen/YWZoGy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SVG image data must have width and height attributes that are not percentages.

Comment: The canvas html element must also be styled as `display:block`