# vis.js library - Rendering a network of nodes with svg and custom html

Tags: javascript, angular, vis.js

I'm working with the **vis.js** library, and rendering nodes with custom HTML via the `svg` tag.

My online project is at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/visjs-with-angular

The problem I'm having is when I attempt to add an image to the `div`, which is inside an `svg`.

You can see the `vis.component.ts` in the 'app\app\vis' folder of my project, and its associated HTML view file.

In the `drawSvgNetwork()` function you will see where I build out the SVG. I figured I'd be able to add a `<i>` tag with a `background-image url`, but it doesn't seem to be rendering when vis.js renders the nodes:

```js
var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="390" height="65">' +
          '<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#7890A7" stroke-width="20" stroke="#ffffff" ></rect>' +
          '<foreignObject x="15" y="10" width="100%" height="100%">' +
          '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:30px">' +
          ' <em>I</em> am' +
          '<span style="color:white; text-shadow:0 0 20px #000000;">' +            
            ' HTML in SVG!</span>' +

          // * THIS IMAGE IS NOT RENDERING * 
          '<i style="background-image: url(https://openclipart.org/download/280615/July-4th-v2B.svg);"></i>' +

          '</div>' +
          '</foreignObject>' +
          '</svg>';
```

i.e. Here is what you will see when running my online project.

[image: visjs network of nodes].

*For reference:

The full online examples are at: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/
And the specific demo page is here (view source to see js code): https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/nodeStyles/HTMLInNodes.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like with `visjs` it's not possible to load an external image inside an SVG, nor in `<foreignObject>`, neither in `<Image>` tag.
Here is an open issue for the problem on github: [Image tag is not loading inside the svg](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3325)

The maintainer of the repository [answered](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3325#issuecomment-322749451) that it was not possible.

A workaround can be found in the same thread (but it may not be suitable for you): **the idea is to load the image separately and render it as dataUrl**

Loading the svg image and converting it to dataUrl:

```
  loadImage(url) {
    const img = new Image();

    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    img.src = url;

    return Observable.fromEvent(img, 'load')
        .map((e: Event) => {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(e.target as HTMLImageElement, 0, 0);
            const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            return dataURL;
        })
  }
```

Using the acquired dataUrl as background instead of the direct svg file url:

```
  '<i style="background-image: url(' + dataUrl + '); display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 20px; background-size: contain;"></i>' +
```

Here is the corrected project https://stackblitz.com/edit/visjs-with-angular-m63jme (I also replaced the svg file, which was used in the original project and contained a US flag, with another arbitrary svg to avoid issues in FF, see below)

### FF issues with rendering svg on canvas

Firefox has some issues with rendering an svg file on canvas, when the file contains `width` and `height` attributes specified as percentages. See the SO questions for more details: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106906/canvas-drawimage-inline-svg-doesnt-work-on-firefox/38107431), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706891/canvas-draw-image-issue-on-firefox-works-well-in-chrome/34713521). So be sure to use an svg with `width` and `height` attributes that are not percentages.

Comment: this certainly looks like a viable option. I will circle back to my old issue at some point and try this out. Much appreciated.

Comment: I see you are loading the US flag svg, but I'm not seeing it rendered anywhere - i.e. `this.loadImage('https://openclipart.org/download/280615/July-4th-v2B.svg').subscribe(
      (dataUrl) => this.drawSvgNetwork(dataUrl) // DRAW SVG WITH CUSTOM HTML
    );`

Comment: It definitely gets rendered OK in Chrome (see the screenshot https://prnt.sc/pkut0w), but I have just checked with FF, and surprisingly the flag is missing :P Will look into that. (BTW what browser are you using?)

Comment: Fixed the project and added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks ! I can see that the dataUrl idea you had works great. I still can't believe I posted this almost a year ago ! THANK YOU.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help